# Getting DocumentId's directly in Google Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I often need the documentId in my local objects after I do a query from Firestore. Since the documentId is no field, I do the following in my queries to achieve this:

```
const ref = fireDb.collection('users')
const query = await ref.where("name", "==", "foo").get()

let users = []

query.forEach((doc) => {
  let user = doc.data()
  user.id = doc.id             /* <-- Here I add the id to the local object*/
  users.push(user)
})
```

Is there an "easier" way to directly get back a document including its id? Or is this how it should be done?

I do not want to duplicate the documentId into a field, that seems kind of redundant even for a NoSql database.

But since this is something I need to do after pretty much ALL MY QUERIES I wonder if Firestore does not have an option to deliver documents including their ID's?

...I guess that's what they call a first world problem? :)

Comment: I don't think there is an easier way to do that. I've been using this same technique on android 

Comment: Thanks, good to know :) I guess that is the way to go. Would be cool however if there is option provided by firebase to always get a document directly with the documentId embedded.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there is currently no option to get the documentId directly embedded into an object.

To reduce boilerplate code and keep my code clean I wrote the following helper function that adds the documentId to every object.

And it does that for collections as well as single documents.

**Helper Function**

```
const queryFirestore = async function (ref) {

  let snapshot = await ref.get()

  switch(ref.constructor.name) {

    /* If reference refers to a collection */
    case "CollectionReference":
    case "Query$$1":
      let items = []
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let item = doc.data()
        item.id = doc.id
        items.push(item)
      })
      return items

    /* If reference refers to a single document */
    case "DocumentReference":
      let documentSnapshot = await ref.get()
      let item = documentSnapshot.data()
      item.id = documentSnapshot.id
      return item
  }
}
```

**Now in my code...**

For a collection:

```
async getUsers() {
  let ref = db.collection("users")
  return await queryFirestore(ref)
}
```

For a single document:

```
async getUser(userId) {
  let ref = db.collection("users").doc(userId)
  return await queryFirestore(ref)
}
```